# RHEL 7 tim ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path-to-shell.sh is not working

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, sudoers

I have a Shell script which is owned by a particular user (`tim:tim`) and with permissions of `755`. For example, if the shell is `test.sh`, the output of `ls -la test.sh` gives:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tim tim 27 Sep 10 01:03 test.sh
```

This shell has commands that should only be run by the `root` user. So what I need is, I need to run this shell script as `sudo test.sh` without prompting for the password. So I added the following entry at the **end** of the `/etc/sudoers` file.

```
tim ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path-to-shell/test.sh
```

But above is not working. It's still asking for the password. But when I add an entry as follows, it works without asking for the password.

```
tim ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

But what I want is, user `tim` should only have the privilege to execute `test.sh` (not all) without prompting for the password.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
sudo test.sh
```

is not same as

```sh
sudo /path-to-shell/test.sh
```

If the sudoers entry:

```
tim ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path-to-shell/test.sh
```

allowed anyone to run a `sudo test.sh` without password, it wold be a critical security weakness, because any user would be able to create a file named `test.sh` and have it executed with `root` privileges.

If your executable/script path is not in the `secure_path` variable from the `/etc/sudoers` file, the `sudo` permission only applies when invoking the command with its full path-name.

> *Now this may be a question for other stack site about system administration*
>   See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path/83194#83194